# How to convert mp4 to YUV file using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I cannot play yuv file properly after converting it from mp4 format to YUV 420 format. I have programmed the width and height of the video when I play it. Is the following converting command for ffmpeg correct?

```
ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p out.yuv
```

Comment: How are you playing it?

Answer (score 5):

Almost all video decodes to YCbCr 4:2:0, aka IYUV ([fourcc](https://www.fourcc.org/pixel-format/yuv-i420/)), hence

```
ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 out.yuv
```

is sufficient.

To view it you can e.g use, `ffplay`, `display` from imagemagick, [my own tool](https://github.com/figgis/yuv-viewer), or [vooya](http://www.offminor.de/).

Some examples:

```
# Using ffmpeg
ffplay -s WxH file.yuv

# Using imagemagick and display to look at first frame
display -size WxH -depth 8 -colorspace sRGB 'file.yuv[1]'
```

Comment: What do you mean? It converts to the format that the original video is encoded in. Check with `ffprobe sample.mp4`. "normally" it says `yuv420p` which is clamped YCbCr 4:2:0 a.k.a IYUV as defined in BT.601.

Comment: `Option -s is deprecated, use -video_size.
[rawvideo demuxer @ 006b6f80] Unable to parse option value "WxH" as image size
[rawvideo demuxer @ 006b6f80] Error setting option video_size to value WxH.`

Comment: You need to set actual values. You can repace -s option, sure.